# Twig Include with a block

Tags: symfony, twig

I need include a twig file with a block, but this file will be added in differents places. The file is this:

```
HTML CODE BLABLA

{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        Code associated with the html
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

With include, is inserted all but not respect order block. 
Also I can load template with "use" but I havent access to the vars :S

```
{% include 'file.html.twig' %} No respect block
{% use 'file.html.twig' %} cant access vars
```

How can I do it ?. (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override a block you have to use the [`extends`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) function. Your template may extends the parent, so the `javascript` block from the sub-template will replace the one from the parent.

You cannot mix `include` and `extend`.

Comment: I dont know why I cannot mix them. This file will be included in differents pages because is a little "widget" for this reason I cant use extends. I think this problem should be very common :S.

Comment: You just have to write your javascript code outside of any `block` in your included template. It's true that it won't be at a particular place in your layout but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [embed](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html) tag?

> The embed tag combines the behaviour of include and extends. It allows you to include another template's contents, just like include does. But it also allows you to override any block defined inside the included template, like when extending a template.

Comment: this is quite the opposite, what OP wants is to be able to include, and that within included file would be able to override block that is in parent

Comment: I expect that's why OP already accepted the other answer. :)